solution to a moving boundary heat equation
I was reading Rubinstein's book 'The Stefan Problem'(https://www.scirp.org/reference/referencespapers?referenceid=1620640) where in chapter2, page 98 he gave an analytical solution to the 1-d moving boundary heat equation in (1.2.5).
\begin{aligned}
u(x, t)= & \left.\int_0^t\left[a^2 v_i(\tau)+w_i(\tau) \dot{\mathrm{X}}_i(\tau)\right] G\left(x, \mathrm{X}_i(\tau), t-\tau\right)\right|_{i=1} ^2 d \tau \\
 & +\int_{\mathrm{X}_1(0)}^{\mathrm{X}_2(0)} \phi(\xi) G(x, \xi, t) d \xi-\left.a^2 \int_0^t w_i(\tau) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} G\left(x, \mathrm{X}_i(\tau), t-\tau\right)\right|_{i=1} ^2 d \tau \\
& +\int_0^t d \tau \int_{\mathrm{X}_1(\tau)}^{\mathrm{X}_2(\tau)} F(\xi, \tau) G(x, \xi, t-\tau) d \xi .
\end{aligned}
using Green's function $\text { the ray } x>x_0$ covering the domain.
I have trouble understanding: 1. why a Green's function of semi-infinite domain can be used to construct intergal solution of a heat equation with finite domain. I was expecting using Green's function of 1-d finite domain, which involves infinte series.
2.It seems to me that $x_0$ can be selected arbitrary if it covers the original domain. Why so?
Thanks in advance for the help.

In dimension 1, the solution on a half space for Dirichlet boundary condition can be reduced to zero boundary condition by adding a constant, so the Greens function is the odd difference of the Greens functions with  mid points mirrored over the boundary, for reflecting boundary the even sum, for mixed boundary a mix.
Transformation of the heat equation to a frame with constant velocity yields a convection term by
$$t\to t', \quad x\to x' + v t', \quad  \partial_x \to \partial_{x'}, \quad \partial_t \to \partial_{t'} + v \partial_{x'} $$
So the Laplacian remains untouched, and its possible to obtain the solution in an oblique system with a time-constant boundary.

So $x_0$ can not be selected arbitarily? The mid point has to be mirrired over the moving boundary?
could you be more specific on the transformation part? How does it answers my questions? Thank you so much!
